# Skydome and dualscreen issues with 14.04 and compiz

Tags: 14.04, compiz, dualhead, cube

[image]

This shows the issue with windows. As you can see they seem to be displayed as though there were 4 cubes. The issue is the same if I use the multiple cubes option as well.

[image]

This shows the skydome issue. Whenever I enable a skydome (the source image is a .jpg) I get this. I have tried with multiple images and using just the gradient, and it's the same every time.

I have no idea how to fix either of these issues and haven't managed to find anything similar while searching, please help!